# Tablets using large and xlarge drawables

Tags: java, android, tablet

I need different sized images for both the 7" and 10" tablets. The 7" images are in drawable-large-mdpi and work fine. The 10" images are in drawable-xlarge-mdpi and work fine. But it now looks like they would probably benefit being all in one folder. I assumed  that just by using drawable-large-mdpi the 10" tablets would automatically go to this but it doesnt seem the case? Is there anyway to get both tablets to use one (large) drawable folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never-mind I just used drawable-sw600dp-mdpi and works fine!

Answer (score 2):

if you have the following set up:
drawable-mdpi   >> 10" and phones will pick up images from here
drawable-large-mdpi  >> 7" will pick up from here

Instead you can have(from 3.2 and above)
drawable-mdpi  >> phones 
drawable-sw600dp-mdpi >> All devices with smallest width greater than 600dp(7" and 10" tabs)

Answer (score 1):

Use sw600dp for 7 inch tablet and sw720dp for 10 inch tablet

Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

`drawable-large-mdpi` and `drawable-large-land-mdpi` for 7" tablet portrait and landscape.

Then for 10" tablet portrait and lanscape `drawable-xlarge-mdpi` and `drawable-xlarge-land-mdpi` respectively.

Working fine. It supports from API level 8